# How to use vb to extract DAX Query into CSV while replacing comma with space

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I found a Macro to export DAX query into CSV, but I'm having trouble with one of the columns where a cell includes a comma. I'm thinking VB didn't really take into consideration for when a resulted cell includes comma. 
What can I change in the VB so that I can replace comma with space before it gets wrriten into CSV file?
Putting this into powerquery isn't really an option, unfortunately...

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExportToCsv()

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim sQuery As String

    'Suppress alerts and screen updates
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    'Bind to active workbook
    Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook

    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'Make sure the model is loaded
    wbTarget.Model.Initialize

    'Send query to the model
    sQuery = "EVALUATE CALCULATETABLE('Query 3')"
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open sQuery,             
    wbTarget.Model.DataModelConnection.ModelConnection.ADOConnection
    Dim CSVData As String
    CSVData = RecordsetToCSV(rs, True)

    'Write to file
    Open "C:\abc.csv" For Binary Access Write As #1
        Put #1, , CSVData
    Close #1

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    ExitPoint:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub

    ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occured - " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly
    Resume ExitPoint
    End Sub



    Public Function RecordsetToCSV(rsData As ADODB.Recordset, _
        Optional ShowColumnNames As Boolean = True, _
        Optional NULLStr As String = "") As String
    'Function returns a string to be saved as .CSV file
    'Option: save column titles

    Dim K As Long, RetStr As String

    If ShowColumnNames Then
        For K = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
            RetStr = RetStr & ",""" & rsData.Fields(K).Name & """"
        Next K

        RetStr = Mid(RetStr, 2) & vbNewLine
    End If

    RetStr = RetStr & """" & rsData.GetString(adClipString, -1, """,""", """" & vbNewLine & """", NULLStr)
    RetStr = Left(RetStr, Len(RetStr) - 3)

    RecordsetToCSV = RetStr
End Function
```

Comment: You might want to use a [`StringBuilder`](https://github.com/retailcoder/VBA-StringBuilder/blob/master/src/StringBuilder.cls) instead of all that string-concatenation... in any case, there's a VBA function named `Replace` in the `VBA.Strings` module that might be of interest.

Comment: Why not use `Range.CopyFromRecordset` and save the worksheet as CSV?